# Using promises in loops correctly javascript

Tags: javascript, api, loops, promise

I am trying to write code that allows me to fetch data from an API sequentially and print out what I received. I have a dictionary of dictionaries which consists of a dictionary of US states whose values are a dictionary of city: city code pairs

```
var cities_forecast_dict = {'Alabama': {'Montgomery':''}, 'Alaska': {'Juneau': ''}, 'Arizona': {'Phoenix': ''}, 'Arkansas': {'Little Rock': ''}, 
'Connecticut': {'Hartford': ''}, 'Delaware': {'Dover': ''}, 'Florida': {'Tallahassee': ''}, 'Georgia': {'Atlanta': ''}, 
'Indiana': {'Indianapolis': ''}, 'Kentucky': {'Frankfort': ''}, 'Maine': {'Augusta': ''}, 'Maryland': {'Annapolis': ''}, 'Massachusetts': {'Boston': ''}, 
'Mississippi': {'Jackson': ''}, 'New Hampshire': {'Concord': ''}, 'New Jersey': {'Trenton': ''}, 'New York': {'Albany': ''}, 'North Carolina': {'Raleigh': ''}, 
'Ohio': {'Columbus': ''}, 'Pennsylvania': {'Harrisburg': ''}, 'Rhode Island': {'Providence': ''}, 'South Carolina': {'Pierre': ''}, 'Tennessee': {'Nashville': ''}, 
'Vermont': {'Montpelier': ''}, 'Virginia': {'Richmond': ''}};
```

My code is supposed to fetch location data from the Accuweather API so that each city respective of its state should have a value that represents its unique id code. The problem is that whenever I try to print out what the `cities_forecast_dict` is I get what its default was when I first created it. In other words, each city's value is just `''`. Im pretty sure it is because the for loops are not in sync with my main code. Others have said that when using promises in loops one should create methods that return promises then iterating over those methods and pushing each returned value into an array on which the `.all()` method could be called on to ensure each promise works, but this hasn't worked for me. I am a noob with promises if you couldn't tell.

```
intialize_location_id()
.then(console.log(cities_forecast_dict));

function intialize_location_id(){
    for(state of Object.keys(cities_forecast_dict)){
        for(city of Object.keys(cities_forecast_dict[state])){
            var country_id = ''
            var state_local_name = ''
            fetch('http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/US/search?apikey=8iaBpn2Bl4GZtA9cgdXZT0dtpW30DGiB&q=' + city)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(loc => { 
                country_id = loc[0]['Country']['ID']
                state_local_name = loc[0]['AdministrativeArea']['LocalizedName']
                if (country_id == 'US' && state_local_name == state){
                    cities_forecast_dict[state][city] = loc[0]['Key']
                }
                else{
                    console.log('error! ' + loc[0]['Country']['ID'] + ' or ' + loc[0]['AdministrativeArea']['LocalizedName']+ 'or'+ city+ ' is not in the dictionary')
                }
            })
            .then(res =>{
                //intialize_forecast_data(state, city);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"whenever I try to print out what the cities_forecast_dict is I get what its default was"*: that's because you are trying to eat the pizza that you ordered, before it was delivered.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yea ik the reason I deleted the other question was cause I realized that in addition to not having followed what you suggested for my code I made a really dumb mistake in it that would have let me discover what you were saying much earlier. But again, thx.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a loop here, `Promise.all` is your friend.

```js
async function getMyResults () {
    const cities = ['Montgomery', 'Juneau'];
    const promises = cities.map(city => `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/US/search?apikey=8iaBpn2Bl4GZtA9cgdXZT0dtpW30DGiB&q=${city}`).then(res => res.json());
    const results = await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that async/await is a far easier way to solve this problem than `Promise.all`

```js
async function request(city, state){
     const res = await fetch('https://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/US/search?apikey=8iaBpn2Bl4GZtA9cgdXZT0dtpW30DGiB&q=' + city);
     const loc = await res.json();
     const country_id = loc[0]['Country']['ID']
     const state_local_name = loc[0]['AdministrativeArea']['LocalizedName'];
     if (country_id == 'US' && state_local_name == state){
          return loc[0]['Key']
      }
      else{
          console.log('error! ' + loc[0]['Country']['ID'] + ' or ' + loc[0]['AdministrativeArea']['LocalizedName']+ 'or'+ city+ ' is not in the dictionary')
          return "";
      }     
}

async function load(input){
   for(state of Object.keys(input)){
        for(city of Object.keys(input[state])){
            input[state][city] = await request(city,state);
        }        
    }
}


async function test(){
  var cities_forecast_dict = {'Alabama': {'Montgomery':''}, 'Alaska': {'Juneau': ''}, 'Arizona': {'Phoenix': ''}, 'Arkansas': {'Little Rock': ''}, 
  'Connecticut': {'Hartford': ''}, 'Delaware': {'Dover': ''}, 'Florida': {'Tallahassee': ''}, 'Georgia': {'Atlanta': ''}, 
  'Indiana': {'Indianapolis': ''}, 'Kentucky': {'Frankfort': ''}, 'Maine': {'Augusta': ''}, 'Maryland': {'Annapolis': ''}, 'Massachusetts': {'Boston': ''}, 
  'Mississippi': {'Jackson': ''}, 'New Hampshire': {'Concord': ''}, 'New Jersey': {'Trenton': ''}, 'New York': {'Albany': ''}, 'North Carolina': {'Raleigh': ''}, 
  'Ohio': {'Columbus': ''}, 'Pennsylvania': {'Harrisburg': ''}, 'Rhode Island': {'Providence': ''}, 'South Carolina': {'Pierre': ''}, 'Tennessee': {'Nashville': ''}, 
  'Vermont': {'Montpelier': ''}, 'Virginia': {'Richmond': ''}};
  await load(cities_forecast_dict);
  console.log(cities_forecast_dict)
}

test();
```